# Pubmed DataSet - Connecting FTP with Flume

Tags: ftp, flume, flume-ng, ncbi, pubmed

To retrieve the datas from Pubmed DataSet [ncbi], I used FireFTP Addon (in firefox) to retrieve the xml, pdf, txt contents. [http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/tools/ftp/]
I have successfully installed Apache Flume.

The main objective is -- I need to connect FTP with Flume and store the final result dataset in Cassandra.

Can anyone help me how to connect FTP Source with Flume.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use flume-ftp-source for this purpose. You can download the source from below link

https://github.com/keedio/flume-ftp-source

Its a maven project so you need to build a jar in order to use it.

Comment: the jar also needs to be placed in <flume home>/lib